# `Socket already opened` error when using `client.connect()` before any Redis command?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am trying to implement Redis in my node project.

Here is how i have initialized my redis instance:

redis.ts:

```
import * as redis from "redis";
import { promisify } from "util";

export const client = redis.createClient();
export const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);
export const setAsync = promisify(client.set).bind(client);

client.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});
```

I have built a todo application. It has a controller that is responsible to fetch a single todo data from the database. The id for the todo is passed as `params`.

Here is the controller code:

```
export const getTodo = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
    
        const todo: any = await Todo.findOne({ include: [Category], where: { id: id, userId: res.locals.userId } });

        res.status(200).json({ message: "todo details", todo: todo});
    } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Before fetching the data from the database, I want to look for the data in the cahche. If i get the data in the cache then I want to send a response else fetch the data from the server and then cache it.

Here is my updated code:

```
export const getTodo = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const cachedTodo = await getAsync(`todo-${id}`);
        if (cachedTodo) {
            res.status(200).json({ message: "todo details", todo: cachedTodo, category: cachedTodo.category.name });
        }

        const todo: any = await Todo.findOne({ include: [Category], where: { id: id, userId: res.locals.userId } });
        await setAsync(`todo-${id}`, todo);

        res.status(200).json({ message: "todo details", todo: todo});
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: getErrorMessage(err) });
    }
};
```

When i tried to run the above code I got an error as `ClientClosedError: The client is closed` . Then i added `await client.connect()` and now I get error as `Socket already opened`.

Please guide me if I am missing something.

When i tried to run the above code I got an error as `ClientClosedError: The client is closed` . Then I added `await client.connect()` above the `getAsync()` command and now I get error as `Socket already opened`.

One more thing I noticed that I am hitting the api endpoints using postman. When I initially hit the route for getting a todo i get see that loading does not stops in postman. I cancel the request and again hit the same endpoint and then I get the error as `Socket already opened`

Please guide me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem or not, but I do notice that you are using promisify with Node Redis. If you are using Node Redis 4.x—which you probably are because why wouldn't you just type `npm install redis` — then this will cause problems as it already implements Promises.

You can just do this (extracted from [README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis)):

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();

await client.set('key', 'value');
const value = await client.get('key');
await client.disconnect();
```

Hope this solves your problem!